# C# Read "list" config file to Dictionary

Tags: c#, config

I want to read a config file that is structured like this

```
ValueA = 0
AnotherValue = -1
SomeText = "Hello World"
```

Is there an easy way to read the entire config file and convert it to an `object` that holds all the values?
I think the easiest way would be to have it be converted to a `Dictionary` and for me to check whether certain keys exist.

I am certain there are certain library that can already do this, but since I have no idea how to call this type of config file I am unable to find anything online. I can only find solutions for XML configs.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: first no... no... just no .... use JSON or XML .... second .. you can use native win32 API for reading ini file ... (beware that `SomeText = "Hello World"` would becom `"Hello World"` not `Hello World` ... because it your custom format not ini)

Comment: .NET Core or .NET Framework? Is this your own custom format (bad idea) or an INI  file? .NET Core's configuration already offers providers for INI and YAML and other formats. Using an *existing* format means you can use all the available tools like syntax checkers, colorizers, linters.

Comment: .NET Core already has an [INI configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ini-configuration-provider) along with JSON and XML providers. Others have created [a YAML configuration provider](https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Configuration). You'll find tools for all three formats, eg as VS Code extensions or command line tools

Answer (score 0):

If the whole file is like that you could simply split on `=`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> config = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(line => line.Trim().Split('='))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length == 2)
    .Select(arr => (Key:arr[0].Trim(), Value:arr[1].Trim()))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .ToDictionary(keyGroup => keyGroup.Key, keyGroup => keyGroup.First().Value);
```

Comment: But the integer values will become strings and string values will then contain extra quotation marks inside

Comment: @T.Dominik: well, then parse them where you need them. No one stops you from creating and initializing a real configuration class from this dictionary. The file itself contains no information about the types of the values.

Comment: Worth to mention that this code snippet will skip the lines containing multiple `=` characters